# How to use * in KEYNAME for ZUNIONSTORE

Tags: redis, sortedset

How can i union 'n' number of sorted sets by using * in Keyname (key-1-1, key-1-,2, key-1-3,..key-1-n) of ZUNIONSTORE command. Is there any other similar option as i have around 55k sortedsets to be joined.

Answer (score 1):

Set operations require explicit key names, not patterns. The only way to do it is the specify each of your 55K keys in the command.

That said, if you're unioning 55K sets, you're probably using it wrong.